# Oracle - Getting proc response quickly even after flushing the buffer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-performance, sqlperformance

I ran a procedure `proc1` and the response time was 300 secs

```
exec proc1; -- 1st run -took 300 secs
```

then I ran

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_CACHE;
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;

exec proc1; -- 2nd run -took 20 secs
```

then again I ran flushed buffer cache and shared pool multiple times but got the result in just 20 secs.

**Question** Why flushing of `buffer_cache` (and `shred_pool`) not able to increase the response? I have checked `v$bh` and it is showing the status as 'free' for all objects. How can I achieve the 1st run's response time ie 300 sec?

**Note** This is being done in development environment for some performance testing and requirement.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting the benefit of file caching on the file server? Also, what is your procedure doing?

Comment: Just noted a good point, I have run the proc1 after ~30 mins and it took 300 secs. It seems running the proc just after flushing the buffer cache is quickly giving the response.

Need to find out what changed happened in this 30 mins which caused the expected slowness. If we are able to find out this then we can directly flush that particular thing also.

Perhaps you're getting the benefit of file caching on the file server?----------didnt get it properly, please explain more

Proc1 is running a big query with many joins and returning result set with the help of sys_refcursor

Comment: By file caching, I mean on the O/S side of things - I.e the O/S itself may have a cache, so instead of Oracle needing to go back to disk post-buffer flush, it might be getting it from the O/S file cache. But it depends on your O/S and other things that I'm not sure about, as I'm not a DBA or an O/S expert.

Comment: Can you please let me know what kind of statement is executing in this procedure?

Comment: its a select query with many joins and returning the result set in ref cursor